# Showing that a distribution can be sampled from 2 uniforms.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Hi there I am looking at the following:

Show that the symmetric triangular distribution,
$$\begin{equation}
  g(x)=\begin{cases}
    0, & \text{if $x<0$}.\\
    x, & \text{$0\leq x\leq1$}\\
    2-x & \text{$1\leq x\leq2$}\\ 
     0& \text{if $x>2$}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}$$

can be sampled from a convolution of 2 uniforms?

Is this related to a inversion technique? Any help would be most appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: No. You are asked to prove that if U and V are i.i.d. uniform on (0,1) then U+V has density g.

Comment: @Did many thanks.